# ROS fuerte and groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it safe to install both and use different versions when needed? Want to test few things in groovy but wanted to make sure it is not going to change things for fuerte.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52234/ros-fuerte-and-groovy/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome to ROS Answers! Please use search before asking questions, as this question was asked only 6 days ago: http://answers.ros.org/question/51713/side-by-side-installation-fuerte-and-groovy/

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1